# Azure loganalytics python SDK always throws MissingApiVersionParameter exception

Tags: python, azure, sdk, azure-log-analytics

I try to follow [MS official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-loganalytics/azure.loganalytics.loganalyticsdataclient?view=azure-python) to get the log from my resource in Azure Log Monitor but never success.
My code is like below.

```
from azure.loganalytics import LogAnalyticsDataClient
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.loganalytics.models import QueryBody

log_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(LogAnalyticsDataClient)

myWorkSpaceId = '1234567890...'
result = log_client.query(myWorkSpaceId, QueryBody(**{'query': 'Heartbeat| limit 50'}))
```

And I always get exception like below:

```
result = log_client.query(myWorkSpaceId, QueryBody(**{'query': 'Heartbeat| limit 50'}))
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/loganalytics/log_analytics_data_client.py", line 121, in query
raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.loganalytics.models.error_response.ErrorResponseException: (MissingApiVersionParameter) The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests
```

I trace code into library in /azure/loganalytics/log_analytics_data_client.py, and dump the url string used for query like below.

```
print(url, query_parameters, header_parameters, body_content)
request = self._client.post(url, query_parameters)
response = self._client.send(request, header_parameters, body_content, stream=False, **operation_config)
```

The output of the url and query information is like below and it look like no version information in between and I doubt this is why I get the exception:
('https://management.azure.com/workspaces/1234567890.../query', {}, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}, {'query': 'Heartbeat| limit 50'})

My azure SDK version is 4.0.0, and my azure-loganalytics library version is v0.1.0, running on Ubuntu.
Does anyone run into same issue or know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dennis, can you open your issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues ? Seems to me it deserve it (I work at MS and can help, but on Github would be better here)

Comment: Hi Laurent, I've added an issue on Github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/4544, please check it.